# Unable to get value from flask dropdown menu

Tags: python, flask, dynamic, graph, dashboard

I am making a dashboard to show different stats from different months. I need to select a month from dropdown, and accordingly the file related to that month will show its graphs on my home.html page.

However my dropdown isnt able to read the month, can I know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code for `app.py`:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect 
from graph_itunes import graphing
import matplotlib
application = Flask(__name__)


def get_itune_installs(ios_path):
    with open (ios_path, 'r') as f:
        install_itunes = json.load(f)

    results = install_itunes['results'][0]['data']

    df_itunes = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results,orient = 'columns')
    return df_itunes

@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def home():

current_userinput = request.form.get('userinput')
path_ios = 'iTunesConnect/Installs/'
ios_path = os.path.join(path_ios, current_userinput)

itunes_installs = get_itune_installs(ios_path)
graph_itunes_installs = graphing(itunes_installs)

return render_template('home.html', 
    graph1 = graph_itunes_installs, 
    userinput = current_userinput)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug = True)
```

Here is my `home.html`:

```
 <form name = 'userinput' action="/" method = 'post'>
        <select  name = "userinput" id = 'userinput'>
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March" selected >March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
            {% for input in userinput %}
                    <option selected value= "{{input}}">{{input}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <p><a class ="btn btn-default" type = "submit" value = "Select" >Submit</a></p>
        </form>
```

Can someone please help me and suggest something?

Comment: Could you post a complete example? What is `userinput` inside your home.html? How do you render this template?

Comment: return render_template('home.html',  
    userinput = current_userinput
    )

Comment: @AndreySemakin do u have any solution to this?

Comment: Please add the full code of `app.py`. Otherwise it is hard to identify the problem.

Comment: @arsho below is the app.py code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am skipping any code related to `matplotlib` and `graphing` package.

Rather, I am showing an example of handling the dropdown value in Flask.
The following example will show value based on the month selected by user.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect 


application = Flask(__name__)

def get_monthly_data(month):
    data = {
        "January": "First month of the year",
        "February": "Second month of the year",
        "March": "Third month of the year",
        "April": "Fourth month of the year",
        "May": "Fifth month of the year"        
    }
    return data.get(month, "Data is not found").strip()

@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        month = request.form.get('month')
        return render_template('home.html', data = get_monthly_data(month))
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug = True)
```

`home.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dropdown Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if data %}
            <div>
                <h3>Monthly Data</h3>
                <p>{{ data }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <select name="month">
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March" selected >March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Select Month">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

Form with month dropdown:

[image: form with month selection dropdown]

Showing result based on user selection:

[image: showing result based on user selection]

Comment: under def home():
I need to get the file name from my directory as the user changes month from dropdown. 
For ex, when use selects Jan, 
`@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        month = request.form.get('month')
        ios_path= os.path.join(ios_ratings, month)
        #here I graph from ios_path which is a csv file
        return render_template('home.html', graph1 = graph_ios, data = get_monthly_data(month))
    return render_template('home.html')`
It gives me error "referenced before local var "month"?Why?

Comment: Python is all about indentation. The code you have pasted in the comment is not readable. Have you run the code I have included in my answer?

Comment: Yes indeed I have. It works fine on its own. My issue is that when a user selects the month from dropdown, the selcted month's path should be attached to my file reader function and display graph accordingly. However, it throws me an error saying "month referenced before local var "month"?

Comment: According to the error message, I guess you are updating values of `month` variable before initialization. Update your question with updated code, expected behavior and error description.

Comment: Thanks @arsho, I managed to figure out the error. And its working! Thanks alot :)

Comment: Great! If you find the answer useful, please accept it. :)